# Who was the boss?

Tags: whos-the-boss

In the TV show "Who's the Boss?", was the answer to the title ever mentioned in the show itself? Was there ever any mention from the writers of the answer to this. Usually a title is said in the pilot episode or it's titled for the characters in the show. As far as I remember though the title was never mentioned in the pilot, or if it was the question was never answered.

To be clear, I am looking for sources from the writer or creator of the show.

Comment: The question wasn't answered because it was rhetorical.

Comment: @Flimzy I understand that but it's always struck me as strange because it is atypical of the naming structure for shows of the time. In almost every other show the title is either said or explained in the pilot. Who's the Boss? was definitely not an atypical sitcom so it's always struck me as weird. Plus ever since Family Guy showed Peter drunkenly saying that Mona was the boss I can't get it out of my head when I think of this classic show.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the title referred to a refrain commonly uttered by frustrated parents. It is a rhetorical question, meaning it is not really a question but a statement. The parent saying "Who's the boss?" is basically telling the kid "you're not in charge -- I am."

I think it was used as a title because it is kind of like a double entendre, in that it could be that the parent saying "Who's the boss?" really isn't the boss. In other words, someone else might really be in charge.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who%27s_the_Boss%3F#Background):

> In early development, the series was titled *You're the Boss*, in reference to Angela employing Tony and the highly unusual gender role reversal. Before the fall 1984 premiere, the producers changed it to *Who's the Boss?*, an open ended title which hinted that any one of the leads could get their own way and be the "boss".

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, Angela is the boss. This video sums it up perfectly:

Comment: That's makes so much sense! I've been over thinking it. Do you have any idea why all of the writing in the clip is backwards though?

Comment: whoever uploaded the video must have just flipped it, the whole thing is backwards

Comment: Wow, I guess I don't know *what's happening* here....

Comment: Some uploaders flip videos in an attempt to avoid copyright infringement. Explanation [here](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110106210623AAaNz9i).

Comment: You might want to summarize the essential parts of the video in order to make this more than a mere link-only answer.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Aside from the fact that, at least in the USA, it appears the video has been pulled due to Sony complaints.