# Who's the negotiator in The Negotiator?

Tags: title, the-negotiator

We have at least 2 negotiators in [The Negotiator](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120768/), but which one is the titular negotiator?

[image]

Comment: But doesn't the tagline right under the title in this pic give it away?

Comment: Yeah actually I guess I it does! The movie has a few different posters with different tag lines... I grabbed this one because it was a good size

Comment: @Walt It seems obvious on the first look indeed, but on the other hand Chris Sabian has quite a significant role, too, and his interaction with Roman is what drives the movie. I'd maybe even go as far and say it applies to both. But I admittedly don't know it either.

Comment: Well, we solved [this](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1470/who-was-the-boss/1487#1487), so don't be discouraged yet. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the title is about one negotiator in particular. It may have been intentionally left open to suit viewer's own perception.

But still if you have to award the title to one of the characters, then I think, Lieutenant Chris Sabian (played by Kevin Spacey) stands as a stronger contender.

This is because, the other character, Danny Roman (Sam L Jackson) is kind of on the back foot, in the story. His fighting skills dominate his negotiation skills.

But Chris Sabian seems more like the one who is talking the talk.

Also please note that in the climax it's Chris who plays his last negotiation card to trick Frost and get him arrested. So based on that Chris Sabian could be awarded the Negotiator title. Although it's just my personal opinion.

Comment: While the reasoning is interesting, I'm not sure I would write off Danny's talking skills that easily. He always keeps the situation and Sabian under control. You're right in that he is more hot-headed than Sabian, but he's still always calculating. Still interesting answer.